# Usage of eloquent taggable package for two columns in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

Hey guys can anyone help me out by explaining the process of using a eloquent taggable package for two columns in Laravel?

Comment: We probably can, but read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first, use the documentation of your package and see if you can get it to work by yourself. We're here to answer questions, not to code your application

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean with `tagging two columns`? You can add multiple tags to a `model` not a specific column.